# Proceed or abort CURL depending on headers

Tags: php, curl, header, download, request

There are certain files that i want to download to my computer. Lots of files are already on my comuter. What i would like to do, is determine whether the online files were changed. I could make conclusions out of the headers that the server gives me about this file. Because I have a lot of files, I want to make the process as efficient as possible so the script is fast.

The headers should be known, so that i could either choose to download the file or not. I want to create a request for the file, that first gets the headers, and as soon as i analysed the header (which would take about 30ms), I want the ability to abort the CURL request.

**I want to get the headers before CURL is done, and I want to have the ability to stop a CURL request.** *If at all possible, it would be great if someone could explain me how to do this with multiple CURL requests at the same time.*

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

This might help you. You can use `get_headers("url")` to get all the headers sent from a specific URL and after that use them as you want. You will find more information about that in the link above.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But specifically need a maximum of 1 request. I want to monitor some values, and right now i have to double my speed in order to keep up.